# Menu items not displaying from config.toml definition

Tags: hugo

I'm attempting to define a site wide menu that is displayed within a bootstrap navbar.

Top level config.toml is;

```
baseURL = "http://localhost/"
languageCode = "en-us"
title = "Localhost"

[menu]
    [[menu.main]]
        identifier = "page1"
        name = "page1"
        url = "/page1/"
        weight = 0
    [[main.menu]]
        identifier = "page2"
        name = "page2"
        url = "/page2/"
        weight = 1
    [[main.menu]]
        identifier = "page3"
        name = "page3"
        url = "/page3/"
        weight = 2
```

The menu sits within a site-header partial that is being passed in the site context.

index.html

```
{{ partial "head.html" . }}

<body>
  {{ partial "site-header.html" . }}

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <main>
        <section>
          <h1>{{.Title}}</h1>
        </section>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

site-header.html

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark ">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ "/" | relURL}}"><img src="/images/Main-Logo-v1-1.png" class="d-inline-block align-top menu-brand-image" alt="Logo"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            {{ $currentPage := . }}
            {{ range .Site.Menus.main }}
              <li class="navbar-item {{if or ($currentPage.IsMenuCurrent "main" .) ($currentPage.HasMenuCurrent "main" .) }} active{{end}}">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ .URL }}" title="{{ .Title }}">{{ .Name }}</a>
              </li>
            {{ end }}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

The {{range .Site.Menus.main }} seems only to parse the first element within the table array [[menu.main]] as the 'page1' entry is all that is included within the generated html.

I've added some debug printf also which confirms that the range only recognises [[menu.main]] as being an array of 1.

Any ideas, pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add `pageRef` to each menu item in config.toml that should be the same as url.

Source 1: [Menus in Hugo](https://harrycresswell.com/writing/menus-in-hugo/)

Source 2: [Hugo release v0.86.0](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/tag/v0.86.0)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have misspelled the other menu entries in `config.toml` menu definition. You are declaring `[[main.menu]]` instead of `[[menu.main]]`. The first one is correct though, that's why it appears.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same problem. when I have started using hugo its version was V0.83.1. when I deploy my website menus where working fine. but after some days menus where not displaying.
[git hub issue link](https://github.com/rhazdon/hugo-theme-hello-friend-ng/issues/308)

after referring above link I have updated to latest version of hugo i.e v0.108.0 and it works. you may check by updating hugo version.